# I keep getting an undefined error on function call

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling to understand why I keep getting a "playerSpeak is undefined" on the code below?

As far as I know I've defined the function playerSpeak() and then tried to call it on the button click. Please can someone give me some insight as to why I keep getting this error?

```js
function playerSpeak() {
  console.log('player');
  player.describeYourself();
}



var player = {};

player.Age = '50',
  player.weight = '50',
  player.describeYourself = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "my name is" + this.name + this.last + ", I'm " + this.Age + "years old" + "and I weight" + this.weight + "I'm light as a feather an quick as a whippet";
  },
```

```html
<button onclick="playerSpeak()">Speak</button>
```

Comment: Hmm this looks fine to me, can you post your whole HTML file?

Comment: Remove the commas from your code the one at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rogue comma at the end of your Javascript. Remove it and you should be good. Oh the little things that we all miss.

Also, instead of using those commas to separate each statement, I would use a semi-colon.

```js
function playerSpeak() {
  console.log('player');
  player.describeYourself();
}



var player = {};

player.Age = '50';
player.weight = '50';
player.describeYourself = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "my name is" + this.name + this.last + ", I'm " + this.Age + "years old" + "and I weight" + this.weight + "I'm light as a feather an quick as a whippet";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="playerSpeak()">Speak</button>
```

Comment: thanks people, for some reason no matter how hard I looked I just completely missed that.